# remote debug from windows to unix ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, classpath, remote-debugging

I'm trying to configure eclipse running on windows to remote debug a java application i have running on a unix box. The remote debugger connects but the Launcher fails with the following stack trace:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 200 [local variables unavailable]  
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
Launcher$AppClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 188 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 306   
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 268    
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 251    
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClassInternal(String) line: 319
```

I have the project src referenced in the Source tab of the debug config, the default dir contains the jars a I need and I checked 'Search for duplicate source files on the path' incase that made any difference... it didn't.

when stepping through I noticed the AppClassLoader has a URLClasspath member called ucp which has the a path ArrayList containing items from the unix classpath (ie unix paths like: /home/example.jar ) - I'm wondering if these are trying to be resolved on windows (the debug session I'm running in eclipse) which is causing the error ??

I've been searching the web for answers all day without luck - has anyone dealt with this before or got and suggestion how to resolve ?

thanks in advance...